# jQuery Resources Not Properly Loading Accordion

Tags: jquery, html, css, load, accordion

I'm trying to build a simple navigation bar for my informational webpage about programming. The problem is actually a bit ironic in the sense that I can't figure out why this code isn't working.

I'm using the GoDaddy WebpageBuilder, but this specific item was added through their HTML element that you can add in. If you've used it before, you know what I'm talking about...

Anyways, the accordion is only loading half of the time. In some occasions it will load and operate perfectly fine; while in other cases it will simple place the extended accordion on the page, but without the accordion.

You can check it out here: [www.shawftware.net](http://www.shawftware.net)

If the problem won't come up on the first try, keep refreshing until you see it; the accordion is in the top right corner of the page.

The error I'm getting in the JavaScript console is this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'accordion'
```

I have no idea what this means or what it does, so I'm hoping someone here understands how to fix this error, and why it's happening only half of the time.

Here's the source code I am running:

HTML:

```
<div id="accordionBox">
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Navigation</h3>
    <div>
    <a href="http://www.shawftware.net/home.html"><p class="navButton" style="color: black">Home</p></a>
    <hr>
    <a href="http://www.shawftware.net/about.html"><p class="navButton">About</p></a>
    <hr>
    <a href="http://www.shawftware.net/contact.html"><p class="navButton">Contact</p></a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
    .gFontHeader{
        font-family: 'Montserrat Subrayada', sans-serif;
        font-size: 34px;
    }
    #accordionBox{
        width: 150px;
    }
    .navButton{
        text-align: center;
        color: #666666;
    }
    .navButton:hover{
        color: black;
    }
    #accordion a{
        text-decoration: none;
    }

</style>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        active: false
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you share your complete full webpage source code ?

Comment: @watou As I mentioned in my post, I've built this in the GoDaddy Website Builder application. I can't upload my own HTML source code through it sadly. If you wanted the full source code, it would look like a large jumbled mess of useless material. The source code for the accordion is really the only thing I can provide because it's the only material I wrote.

Comment: Worth a try: Move  `<script> $(document).ready(function(){ $( "#accordion" ).accordion({ collapsible: true, active: false }); }); </script>` to the bottom of your html just above the `</body>` tag.. I'm thinking maybe `jquery-ui` is not all the way loaded sometimes when your script calls `accordian`

Comment: @Trevor The error is still there. It's also giving the same error message.

Comment: I'm wondering if one of your scripts later on is disabling the `jquery-ui` or something.. Could you try commenting out or removing a number a scripts until you just have the `jquery, jquery-ui` scripts running..  Just to see if you can still reproduce the problem?

Comment: `<meta charset="utf-8">

<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat+Subrayada" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.iconj.com/ico/y/p/ypcyuauh3b.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="”apple-touch-icon”" href="”http://www.iconj.com/ico/y/p/ypcyuauh3b.ico”">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>`
Those are the only scripts I'm using.

Comment: @Zulfe, I'm not that `accordion` is the suitable widget for your need !, I think you should use [menu widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/).

Comment: @watou Wow, I didn't know that was available! I'll make sure to check that out. I'm looking for something compact that folds, which is why I gravitated towards the accordion widget.

Comment: I just tested locally, and the accordion works as expected on my local apache server (even if it's terribly heavy to use jQuery UI just for a simple menu, while it could be simply done with slideDown & slideUp). Moreover i noticed you load 3 times jQuery and 2 times jQuery UI ! jQuery is already loaded by a require(), then the following tags are present twice in your page `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using two jquery files.

- jQuery JavaScript Library v1.8.3
- jQuery JavaScript Library v1.9.1

Please remove the older version of jquery and check if it works fine.

Comment: Where are you seeing v1.8.3 and v1.9.1?

Comment: I saw it in the resources tab in chrome inspect element.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the GoDadday Hosting connection to install an Application (jQuery) using their web interface before I could get jQuery to work correctly.  Their upload process using ftp adds lines into the documents you upload... it's a pain in the bum.